# How to generate 3D chart with doughnut hole in Charts Service using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

When one creates a chart in Google Sheets, one may, via the dialogs, create a 3D pie chart **with a doughnut hole**. If you try to do that with Charts Service it doesn't work and [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart) is quite straight forward on that score:

> You can't combine the pieHole and is3D options; if you do, pieHole will be ignored.

Now using the following code

```js
function myOTherFunction() {
    const sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(INSERT_YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID_HERE).sheets;
    for (let sheet of sheets) {
        const charts = sheet.charts;
        if (charts)
            for (let chart of charts) {
                Logger.log("Sheet %s, Chart %s, JSON '%s'", sheet.properties.title, String(chart.chartId), JSON.stringify(chart.spec));
            }
    }
}
```

for one of the charts I get the following JSON

```json
{
    "hiddenDimensionStrategy": "SKIP_HIDDEN_ROWS_AND_COLUMNS",
    "pieChart": {
        "domain": {
            "sourceRange": {
                "sources": [{
                        "endRowIndex": 21,
                        "sheetId": 1962284759,
                        "startRowIndex": 11,
                        "startColumnIndex": 12,
                        "endColumnIndex": 13
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "threeDimensional": true,
        "pieHole": 0.5,
        "series": {
            "sourceRange": {
                "sources": [{
                        "startRowIndex": 11,
                        "endRowIndex": 21,
                        "startColumnIndex": 11,
                        "endColumnIndex": 12,
                        "sheetId": 1962284759
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "subtitleTextFormat": {
        "foregroundColorStyle": {
            "rgbColor": {
                "red": 0.4,
                "green": 0.4,
                "blue": 0.4
            }
        },
        "fontSize": 30,
        "foregroundColor": {
            "red": 0.4,
            "blue": 0.4,
            "green": 0.4
        },
        "fontFamily": "serif"
    },
    "fontName": "serif",
    "subtitle": "No Name"
}
```

Interestingly, in `pieChart` there's a setting `"threeDimensional": true` which I expect is analogous to the `is3D` setting that one cannot use as per the aforementioned documentation. So where does it go? The following doesn't work

```js
  var chart = Charts.newPieChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .setOption('subtitle', 'Attractions Sw')
    .setOption('subtitleTextStyle.fontSize', 30)
    .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.fontSize', 12)
    .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.bold', true)
    .setOption('sliceVisibilityThreshold', 0)
    .setOption('pieHole', 0.3)
    .setOption('legend.position', 'labeled')
    .setOption('pieSliceText', 'label')
    .setOption('pieChart.threeDimensional', true)
    .setDimensions(595, 300)
    .build();
```

So there's where I hit a brick wall. There's `is3D` and there's `pieChart.threeDimensional` and I still can't get a programmatically created 3D pie graph **with a doughnut hole**!. What the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create 3D pie chart using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that it cannot be achieved with Spreadsheet service using SpreadsheetApp. In order to create the 3D chart using Google Apps Script, it is required to use Sheets API.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use Sheets API as a workaround. Fortunately, I think that your JSON object in your question can be used for creating the 3D pie chart.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the sheet name for your situation. In this script, I used your JSON object in your question by adding a property of `position`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getSheetId();
  const resource = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "addChart": {
          "chart": {
            "spec": {
              "hiddenDimensionStrategy": "SKIP_HIDDEN_ROWS_AND_COLUMNS",
              "pieChart": {
                "domain": {
                  "sourceRange": {
                    "sources": [
                      {
                        "endRowIndex": 5,
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endColumnIndex": 1
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "threeDimensional": true,
                "pieHole": 0.5,
                "series": {
                  "sourceRange": {
                    "sources": [
                      {
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "endRowIndex": 5,
                        "startColumnIndex": 1,
                        "endColumnIndex": 2,
                        "sheetId": sheetId
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "subtitleTextFormat": {
                "foregroundColorStyle": {
                  "rgbColor": {
                    "red": 0.4,
                    "green": 0.4,
                    "blue": 0.4
                  }
                },
                "fontSize": 30,
                "foregroundColor": {
                  "red": 0.4,
                  "blue": 0.4,
                  "green": 0.4
                },
                "fontFamily": "serif"
              },
              "fontName": "serif",
              "subtitle": "No Name"
            },
            "position": {  // <--- Added
              "overlayPosition": {
                "anchorCell": {
                  "sheetId": 0,
                  "rowIndex": 0,
                  "columnIndex": 3
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, the data is retrieved from the cells `A1:B5`. This sample values are from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addchartrequest)